# Trouble with ListView onClick

Tags: java, android, listview, onclick, adapter

I have a ListView that is contained in a fragment. When an item is clicked on the listview I want it to execute some code but the code that is executed depends on which item on the List was clicked. Here is my code for the fragment that contains the ListView:

```
public class ListViewer extends Fragment {
private ListView list;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInsanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list_view, container, false);

    Player player_data[] = new Player[] {
        new Player(R.drawable.bschenn1, "Brayden Schenn", "Age: 21, Drafted 5th overall by LA King in 2009",  "Center - #10"),  
        new Player(R.drawable.giroux, "Claude Giroux", "Age: 25, Drafted 22nd overall by Philadelphia Flyers in 2006", "Center - #28"),
        new Player(R.drawable.hartnell, "Scott Hartnell", "Age: 30, Drafted 6th overall by Nashville Predators in 2000", "Left Wing - #19")
    };

    PlayerAdapter adapter = new PlayerAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_row, player_data);

    list = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list);

    View header = (View)inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, null);

    list.addHeaderView(header);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    return v;
}
}
```

Here is the code to the Adapter:

```
public class PlayerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Player> {
Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
Player data[] = null;

public PlayerAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Player[] data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    PlayerHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new PlayerHolder();
        holder.imageIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
        holder.txtplayerName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.txtageDraft = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.artist);
        holder.txtpositionSNum = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.duration);

        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (PlayerHolder)row.getTag();
    }
     Player player = data[position];
     holder.imageIcon.setImageResource(player.image);
     holder.txtplayerName.setText(player.playerName);
     holder.txtageDraft.setText(player.ageDraft);
     holder.txtpositionSNum.setText(player.positionSweaterNum);

     return row;
}

static class PlayerHolder {
    ImageView imageIcon;
    TextView txtplayerName;
    TextView txtageDraft;
    TextView txtpositionSNum;
}

}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a listener to the listview to detect touch events.

```
list.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() 
{
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parentView, View childView, int position, long id) 
 {
    //here you have the position so you can do whatever you want with this item


 }
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry my debugger is acting up I will check your answer and accept it as soon as I get my debugger to work and try it. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add OnItemClickListener to your list object:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: But how will I know which one is clicked? When I do this and click on one of them i do a Log to see the position and the position changes every time I close and open the app.

Comment: you override onItemClick method that receive int position parameter which is the currently clicked position in the list.